# Is there some way of finding a missing SharePoint user?

Tags: java, sharepoint, web

So I have administrator privileges to a SharePoint site. The site crashes on loading due to a user not found. I keep getting this error:

```
Microsoft.SharePoint.SPException: User cannot be found. 
at   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPUserCollection.get_Item(String loginName)
```

I have access to the server code to view it, but not for running purposes. I know it has something to do with a new migration of users.

Does anyone know if there’s any way using the SharePoint administrative functions to view which invalid user causes a site crash?

Comment: Which version of SharePoint is this for?

Comment: Where is the error occurring? On server startup? When a workflow is being published or running? Web page view?

Comment: It crashes when you go to the web page aka in browser

Comment: Is it a specific page on the web site (mysite, main site, report, admin page, etc) or any page? Does this happen to all users or just you/specific user?

Comment: It happens to all users on a specific page. it's just a normal created page only in user mode. not admin mode

Comment: Can you check the page or workflow (ex: http://erinbglenn.com/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=28) through SharePoint designer All Files to see who changed the page last edited it/saved it/owns it? That may show it to you easily. If that doesn't show you the name of the user, you'll need to go to the ULS logs and get the full error (check the link above for an example of the full error for user not found) that should show what it is trying to do when it fails the user lookup (workflow association, saved document, etc).